# postDelayed function starting 4x faster than specified

Tags: android

I'm trying to update the canvas every 100ms using postDelayed() and then invalidate() (which calls onDraw again), but for some reason it will update by 30-50ms. I have debug messages printing out every time the onUpdate() function is called and the timestamps are spaced apart by 30-50ms. Why is it going so much faster than I want it to go? Usually, you'd expect functions run using a delay to be slower than what you specified.

```
private int FRAME_RATE = 100;

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    onDrawAnimation(c);

    // Delay the next update by FRAME_RATE milliseconds
    _h.postDelayed(_game_loop, FRAME_RATE);
}

private Runnable _game_loop = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!_paused) {
            onUpdate(); // Update locations/speed
            invalidate(); // Update visuals (ends up calling onDraw)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: don't call _h.postDelayed(_game_loop, FRAME_RATE); in onDraw as onDraw is called by a system,  call it from your Runnable instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this.

```
private Runnable _game_loop = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        _h.postDelayed(_game_loop, FRAME_RATE);
        if (!_paused) {
            onUpdate(); // Update locations/speed
            invalidate(); // Update visuals (ends up calling onDraw)
        }
    }
};
```

Also, don't forget to remove all delayed callbacks:

```
public void onPause(){
    _h.removeCallbacks(_game_loop);
    // or _h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); 
    // to remove everything
}
```

You will probably want to separate `onUpdate()` and `invalidate()` in different methods and call them at different intervals.

Usually, you need to update the visuals much more often than the game logic, and you want to keep the visual refresh as lightweight as possible. In you code, if you are doing something that takes longer than 100 milliseconds, you will get visible stuttering.